# Raspberry Pi - Capture GPIO input and ignore others for 10 seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

So I've created the following code to capture input from three GPIO terminals of a Raspberry PI 3 B+. This code does what I want, EXCEPT there seems to be a buffer and the event_detect system that I want to clear once the first input becomes active.  The purpose of this program is for a game-show like experience of people trying to buzz in at the same time.  But there can only be one "first" person to buzz in. The program should detect the first active input and basically ignore the rest for 10 seconds.

PS - I'm very novice to Python and the specifics of the Raspberry pi.

PPS - I've reduced the timer to 3 seconds to make it easier to troubleshoot.

```
# External module imports
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import time

# This procedure will watch three inputs and lock in the team that calls in first for 10seconds
# Change the colors of the buttons to show which team pressed in first.

def action1(dunno):
        # Team1 button pressed
        team1_btn.bg="green"
        team2_btn.bg="red"
        team3_btn.bg="red"
        sleep10()

def action2(dunno):
        # Team1 button pressed
        team1_btn.bg="red"
        team2_btn.bg="green"
        team3_btn.bg="red"
        sleep10()

def action3(dunno):
        # Team1 button pressed
        team1_btn.bg="red"
        team2_btn.bg="red"
        team3_btn.bg="green"
        sleep10()

def sleep10():
        #sleep for 10 seconds
        delay_timer.visible=True
        for i in range(3,0,-1):
                delay_timer.value=str(i)
                time.sleep(1)
        delay_timer.visible=False
        team1_btn.bg="light grey"
        team2_btn.bg="light grey"
        team3_btn.bg="light grey"


# Pin setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Broadcom pin-numbering scheme
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING, callback=action1, bouncetime=1800)
GPIO.add_event_detect(20, GPIO.RISING, callback=action2, bouncetime=1800)
GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.RISING, callback=action3, bouncetime=1800)


app = App(title="A07 DSS Tri-State - Jeopardy", width=700)
blank1 = Text(app, text="")
welcome_message = Text(app, text="This..      is..       Jeopardy!!", size=30, font="Times New Roman", color="blue")

blank2 = Text(app, text="")
blank3 = Text(app, text="")

team1_btn = PushButton(app, text="Team Black & Blue")
team1_btn.bg="light grey"
blank4 = Text(app, text="")
team2_btn = PushButton(app, text="Team Holiday Spirit")
team2_btn.bg="light grey"
blank5 = Text(app, text="")
team3_btn = PushButton(app, text="Team Creamsicle")
team3_btn.bg="light grey"
blank6 = Text(app, text="")
delay_timer = Text(app, text="0")
delay_timer.visible=False

app.display()
```

Comment: 1. You can make a function to add event callbacks and delete them. Then after hit, you disable the callbacks, do the cooldown like now, then enable them again. 2. Another solution is not wait in the callback but set some variable (boolean flag) that would disable the callbacks from inside (do the whole contents of callbacks in ifs). Another thread would check that variable over time, if it notices the flag is set, it would then start the cooldown and check the flag back to activate the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was able to get the extra inputs to be ignored by using some time comparisons after the first input comes in.  The balance of the inputs are ignored for x amount of seconds.